# Fatal error when including certain custom fields in Activity Report

Tags: custom-fields, civireport, activities

I noticed that a couple of our reports had broken after the update to 4.7 (on Drupal), and trying to recreate the reports brings up the same error, with a message saying 'DB Error: no such field'

Mostly the activity report works fine, and most of the reports involving custom data are okay, but there's one particular custom data set that generates a fatal error. We're also using the Extended Reports extension, and the Activity reports from that don't have a problem with this data set.

From the error log (this is for just one custom field selected, but I get similar errors for other or multiple fields):

```
Feb 12 11:07:08  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => handle
    )

[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS
SELECT civicrm_contact_target.sort_name as civicrm_contact_contact_target, civicrm_contact_target.id as civicrm_contact_contact_target_id, activity_civireport.id as civicrm_activity_id, activity_civireport.source_record_id as civicrm_activity_source_record_id, activity_civireport.activity_type_id as civicrm_activity_activity_type_id, activity_civireport.subject as civicrm_activity_activity_subject, activity_civireport.activity_date_time as civicrm_activity_activity_date_time, activity_civireport.status_id as civicrm_activity_status_id, address_civireport.country_id as civicrm_address_country_id, value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport.what_is_your_postcode__179 as civicrm_value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_custom_179, address_civireport.street_name as civicrm_address_street_name, address_civireport.street_number as civicrm_address_street_number, address_civireport.street_address as civicrm_address_street_address, address_civireport.city as civicrm_address_city, address_civireport.postal_code as civicrm_address_postal_code  
    FROM civicrm_activity activity_civireport
         INNER JOIN civicrm_activity_contact  activity_contact_civireport
                ON activity_civireport.id = activity_contact_civireport.activity_id AND
                   activity_contact_civireport.record_type_id = 3
         INNER JOIN civicrm_contact civicrm_contact_target
                ON activity_contact_civireport.contact_id = civicrm_contact_target.id

             LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address_civireport
                       ON (civicrm_contact_target.id =
                           address_civireport.contact_id) AND
                           address_civireport.is_primary = 1
  WHERE activity_civireport.is_test = 0 AND
                            activity_civireport.is_deleted = 0 AND
                            activity_civireport.is_current_revision = 1 AND ( activity_civireport.activity_type_id IN (23) )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport.what_is_your_postcode__179' in 'field list']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS
SELECT civicrm_contact_target.sort_name as civicrm_contact_contact_target, civicrm_contact_target.id as civicrm_contact_contact_target_id, activity_civireport.id as civicrm_activity_id, activity_civireport.source_record_id as civicrm_activity_source_record_id, activity_civireport.activity_type_id as civicrm_activity_activity_type_id, activity_civireport.subject as civicrm_activity_activity_subject, activity_civireport.activity_date_time as civicrm_activity_activity_date_time, activity_civireport.status_id as civicrm_activity_status_id, address_civireport.country_id as civicrm_address_country_id, value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport.what_is_your_postcode__179 as civicrm_value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_custom_179, address_civireport.street_name as civicrm_address_street_name, address_civireport.street_number as civicrm_address_street_number, address_civireport.street_address as civicrm_address_street_address, address_civireport.city as civicrm_address_city, address_civireport.postal_code as civicrm_address_postal_code  
    FROM civicrm_activity activity_civireport
         INNER JOIN civicrm_activity_contact  activity_contact_civireport
                ON activity_civireport.id = activity_contact_civireport.activity_id AND
                   activity_contact_civireport.record_type_id = 3
         INNER JOIN civicrm_contact civicrm_contact_target
                ON activity_contact_civireport.contact_id = civicrm_contact_target.id

             LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address_civireport
                       ON (civicrm_contact_target.id =
                           address_civireport.contact_id) AND
                           address_civireport.is_primary = 1
  WHERE activity_civireport.is_test = 0 AND
                            activity_civireport.is_deleted = 0 AND
                            activity_civireport.is_current_revision = 1 AND ( activity_civireport.activity_type_id IN (23) )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport.what_is_your_postcode__179' in 'field list']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS
SELECT civicrm_contact_target.sort_name as civicrm_contact_contact_target, civicrm_contact_target.id as civicrm_contact_contact_target_id, activity_civireport.id as civicrm_activity_id, activity_civireport.source_record_id as civicrm_activity_source_record_id, activity_civireport.activity_type_id as civicrm_activity_activity_type_id, activity_civireport.subject as civicrm_activity_activity_subject, activity_civireport.activity_date_time as civicrm_activity_activity_date_time, activity_civireport.status_id as civicrm_activity_status_id, address_civireport.country_id as civicrm_address_country_id, value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport.what_is_your_postcode__179 as civicrm_value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_custom_179, address_civireport.street_name as civicrm_address_street_name, address_civireport.street_number as civicrm_address_street_number, address_civireport.street_address as civicrm_address_street_address, address_civireport.city as civicrm_address_city, address_civireport.postal_code as civicrm_address_postal_code  
    FROM civicrm_activity activity_civireport
         INNER JOIN civicrm_activity_contact  activity_contact_civireport
                ON activity_civireport.id = activity_contact_civireport.activity_id AND
                   activity_contact_civireport.record_type_id = 3
         INNER JOIN civicrm_contact civicrm_contact_target
                ON activity_contact_civireport.contact_id = civicrm_contact_target.id

             LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address_civireport
                       ON (civicrm_contact_target.id =
                           address_civireport.contact_id) AND
                           address_civireport.is_primary = 1
  WHERE activity_civireport.is_test = 0 AND
                            activity_civireport.is_deleted = 0 AND
                            activity_civireport.is_current_revision = 1 AND ( activity_civireport.activity_type_id IN (23) )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport.what_is_your_postcode__179' in 'field list']"]
)


Feb 12 11:07:08  [info] $backTrace = #0 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php(235): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...")
#4 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-19, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...")
#5 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport.what...")
#7 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...")
#9 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(2435): DB_common->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...")
#10 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(1627): DB_DataObject->_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...")
#11 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(334): DB_DataObject->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...")
#12 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(1209): CRM_Core_DAO->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...", TRUE)
#13 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Report\Form\Activity.php(775): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civireport_activity_temp_target CHARACTER SET utf8 COL...")
#14 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Form.php(423): CRM_Report_Form_Activity->postProcess()
#15 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\QuickForm\Action\Submit.php(74): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#16 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Submit->perform(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Activity), "submit")
#17 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\HTML\QuickForm\Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Activity), "submit")
#18 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("submit")
#19 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#20 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Report\Page\Report.php(72): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Report_Form_Activity", NULL, NULL)
#21 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(312): CRM_Report_Page_Report->run((Array:3), NULL)
#22 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#23 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#24 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\sites\all\modules\civicrm\drupal\civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#25 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("report", "activity")
#26 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\includes\menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#27 C:\xampper\htdocs\able\index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#28 {main}
```

(Just double-checked, and I'm also unable to filter the Activity Report with these custom fields)

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18048 is the issue in JIRA for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the isssue might be based on the lenght of the table name of field name> I recollect we had an issue with that quite some time ago

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the DB and see if this table actually exists in your local and (if relevant) upstream DB copies?

If the table doesn't exist locally *only* but does elsewhere, that might point to a failed import or a limitation of your local MySQL environment (eg filename limit on windows MySQL).

If the table doesn't exist at all, perhaps try recreating the custom data group with a shorter name? According to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6868302/43034 the limit is 64 char so this may not be the cause.

Comment: The table holding the data, civicrm_value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33, is definitely there. The error log refers to value_gwl_hears_me_equal_opps_form_33_civireport, but I'd assumed this was referring to the temp table?

Comment: Yes. So either the query generator has generated a bad query, or CiviCRM thinks you have a table which you don't. Can you confirm that `value_gwl_*` table does NOT exist? I suspect you need some professional help to debug this.

Comment: The value_gwl_..._civireport table doesn't exist (there's no table named in that form in the db).

Comment: I had another look at this and tried to replicate the error with a longer field set name, and was able to replicate it on both my installation and the 4.7 demo. I'm going to raise it as an issue - thank you for helping me sound this out.

Comment: @ChrisBurgess do you know the OP isn't a professional, or are you just assuming? Her/his comments and question seem pretty knowledgable to me!

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part! What I probably meant was "(someone) will need to take this apart and debug what's happening inside". Some bugs are less easy to diagnose via SE format and direct access will save a lot of back and forth. @liblogger my apologies for any apparent disrespect, none intended. Did you open a JIRA on this?

Comment: No problem, I got your meaning :) I did open an issue - it's the one you posted above.

Comment: FWIW, value_gwl_... is neither an alias or table in the query's FROM.

Comment: My guess is there's code in the query generator trying to avoid some other bug by cutting off table names longer than 50 characters.